# Passing output parameter of one test case to input parameter of the other test case in HP QC

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center

Is there a way of passing output parameter of one test case as the input parameter of the another test case in HP QC 10 (test cases are automation Test script generated in QTP), so that when test cases are run together (in sequential order) in a Test Set information (parameters) generated in one test case can be used for execution of other test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using parameter() syntax in your QTP script. You can use below code for sending parameters to your actions.

```
RunAction <Action name>, oneiteration, input parameter1, input parameter2, output parameter1, output parameter 2 .. and so on...
```